# Play music on Hi-Fi via Airplay from Kubuntu

Tags: audio, kubuntu, airplay

I would like to use the Airplay functionality of my [Hi-Fi System](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/dab-systems/cmt-g2bnip) from my Linux Kubuntu. I was able to make the Hi-Fi play songs using [Bubble UPNP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) from an Android tablet.

How can I use a music player like [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) to play music from my Kubuntu system using Airplay?

Answer (score 0):

I've used MediaTomb as an DLNA Server under Xubuntu, because it is controlled with a webinterface it should work with KDE just as well.
[MediaTomb installation description](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Mediatomb)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but due to my very limited knowledge I though Airplay and UPNP was more or less the same :(. Please check the new version of the question...